# Multiple EC2 instances preventing phpMyAdmin login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds, amazon-elb

I have an AWS elastic load balancer connected to between 1 and 3 EC2 instances, which are connected to a single RDS database via phpMyAdmin.

When logging into phpMyAdmin, I can successfully log in and access the database when I have only ONE EC2 instance active. However when I have 2 or more, the phpMyAdmin login page simply stays when logging in. It does however return proper errors for incorrect info, but displays no extra info for accurate credentials.

This is bugging me to death! Please help!

Comment: You have one of two possible answers, below (the other option, seemingly obvious enough, is to choose an instance and connect directly to it)... but, seriously, now.... If you have phpmyadmin exposed to the Internet... and, worse, on production servers... you are practically *begging* for something "unexpected" to happen.  "Yes, the keys are in the ignition... but the doors are locked... so I think the car should be fine."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your load balancer is using a Round Robin algorithm to balance the traffic on the EC2 instances. Enable Session based Algorithm on your ELB and this issue will be resolved.

Check this Guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-duration

Comment: Exactly the problem. I would think this would be changed by default when there are more than one instances. Thank you!